# Behavior of page when loaded into Facebook application tab

Tags: facebook

When a user visits my site "www.mysite.com" I set a cookie for that specific user.
Next the user goes to Facebook, lands on an application tab and clicks the like button. An external page "www.mysite.com/facebooktab.html" is loaded into the Facebook canvas. 
1. Now, do I have access from facebooktab.html to the cookie I set on www.mysite.com earlier?
2. Does the page loaded into Facebook show the same behaviour as when I would just visit www.mysite.com/facebooktab.html in my browser, except that when the page is loaded within Facebook I have some additional user properties available to me (since user is logged in in Facebook)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical difference between the two scenarios is that when your page is loaded directly, the cookies you set/read are "first party" cookies; when your page is loaded inside the Facebook framework, the cookies become "third party".  Each browser has its own set of rules, but they all apply different policies to third-party cookies versus first party cookies.  You mentioned you are initially setting the cookie directly on your website (first-party mode), and then only reading it when the page is inside Facebook (third-party mode).  Most browsers will allow that with no restrictions, as they only apply stricter third-party policies to the writing of cookies and not reading. The exception is Firefox, which lumps reading and writing permissions together. If a Firefox user has cleared the "Accept third-party cookies" box in their configuration, your page on Facebook will not be able to read the cookie you set earlier even though it was set directly on your website.

Comment: So, to be sure, the other way around: when user starts with a visit to my Facebook page and I set a cookie, this is a 3rd party cookie? And when the user then goes to my website and I want to see what data was set in the cookie when he was on Facebook, in Firefox, depending on configuration, I might not be able to read from it?

Comment: Doing it that way (setting a cookie from within a Facebook page) you are writing a third-party cookie, and things get much more complicated -- you have to take into account the behavior of different browsers as well as the user's specific configuration. If I remember correctly Safari is the most restrictive in its default config; Firefox and Chrome allow writing by default but are often changed by the user; IE has some silly default rules that won't allow a write unless you also send an appropriate P3P header. The bottom line is, you can never depend on all users being able to set the cookie.